# Regex to match char/digit/digit/digit

Tags: javascript, regex

In fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rtucgv74/

I'm attempting to match the first char with 3 digits. So below code should alert `f234`. But instead null is returned ?

src :

```
var reg = /^\[a-zA-Z]\d{3}/;

alert(reg.exec(("test f234 sadfas")[1]))
```

How do extract char/digit/digit/digit from string ?

Comment: Should it not be `reg = /^[a-zA-Z]\d{3}/;` without backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost right, but the first backslash in your regex is making the `[` match an actual bracket instead of defining a character set.

And the `^` is preventing it from matching anything not at the beginning of the string.

So the correct regex is `/[a-zA-Z]\d{3}/` or `/[a-z]\d{3}/i`

The other problem is that you try to read the second element of the result array. But you're not capturing anything in your regex, so there will be only one element (`[0]`) which is the whole match.

Try:

```
reg.exec("test f234 sadfas")[0]
```

Comment: what is char i in regex performing ?

Comment: @blue-sky it's a flag making the regex case-insensitive.

Comment: ah, right… hadn't noticed that other issue in your code… editing my answer, give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

The \ in your regex escapes character [ and makes it non special. And the character ^ prevents your regex to match any part that is not in the beginning of the string.

So this would work :

```
var reg = /[a-zA-Z]\d{3}/;
alert(reg.exec("test f234 sadfas")[0]);
```

Note that there is only one element in the result because your regex don't contain any capture (characters between brackets).

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var reg = /[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}/;

alert("test f234 asdfghj".match(reg))
```

[Check the Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k42r9r84/2/)

UPDATE WITH BOUNDARY SUPPORT:

The regex will match also part of words like ab**c123**35 so to void this behaviour you could try this regex:

```
var reg = /\b[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}\b/;

alert("test aaf23412 asdfghj".match(reg)) // not match
alert("test f234 asdfghj".match(reg)) // match !
alert("test f2343 asdfghj".match(reg)) // not match
```

[Check the demo fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/k4k0eo0j/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are picking out a string from a "sentence", so remove the `^`. Also remove the `\` that escapes the `[`. So you want:

```
[a-zA-Z]\d{3}
```

Test it here: http://regexr.com/3bta7

Answer (score -1):

This can help you find the first character occurring before 3 digits:

***\w(?=\d{3})***.

Comment: unfortunately, `\w` also matches digits.